# vis.js Network Manipulation: Split Node label onto different lines

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using vis.4.18.1.
I have an interactive chart and nodes can be added or edited by clicking on the map using `addNode()` and `editNode()`.
How can I set the Node label on multiple lines?
I am collecting the label data using a pop-up form.
I know this can be done when importing initial chart data when the map is created by using newline but this does not work interactively and the node label looks like:
'John Smith\nDate of birth'.
I have also tried setting node font to multi and using html br but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something along the lines of:

```
node.username = "John Smith";
node.dateOfBirth = "Jun 18th 1978";
node.label = node.username + "\n" + node.dateOfBirth;
```

You may extend your node object by properties not inherent to visJS nodes/dataSet. Maybe that way you can work around your issue.

**Edit:** I just tested this example where node.label = node.title on the initial render and gets expanded when the node is selected.

```
function expandNode(selectedNode){
  selectedNode.label = selectedNode.title + '\n' + 'a' + '\n' + 'b' + '\n' + selectedNode.problem;
  nodesObj.update(selectedNode); 
}

network.on('select', function(selection){
  let selectedNodes = nodesObj.get(selection.nodes); // nodesObj is a visjs dataSet
  if(selection.nodes.length === 1){
    expandNode(selectedNodes[0]);
  }
}
```

[image: Collapsed Node]
[image: Expanded Node]

Collapsed & expanded node

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response. I have tried this and it displays the multiple strings on one line with newlines as noted above.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle reproducing your issue? I extended the original reply with a short example that achieves the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: You beauty! Your example made me rethink my existing tries and it now works - thank you so much!

Comment: I like this technique... keep the network tidy and show extra info as needed. To make this work, I had to make a small syntax change on the last line to close out the call to `network.on`. I changed the last line to `});`